# Mediation between Hibernate Entity Listeners and netty-socketio

Tags: java, hibernate, socket.io, jpa-2.1, hibernate-entitymanager

I am working on a small Java project, and here's the basic idea of what I'm trying to achieve: I have a layer over netty-socketio that accepts socket.io requests from the browser, and I use JPA 2.1/hibernate to persist the requested changes to DB. The twist is that I have a concept of stream requests as well, as in a user will request the current state of a collection and all future updates. To get the real-time updates from the DB, I'm using Entity Listeners. I'm looking for a solid way of connecting the entity listener methods to the handler on top of the socketio connection, i.e. the stream handler should be notified when the data it's interested in changed so it can send the update down the pipe. I tried to come up with a singleton moderator of sorts to which the entity listeners could post updates, and subscribed handlers could consume it, all based on a `String topic`, pretty much like a pubsub. The problem I hit was this: let's take for example the POJO `User`. When a new `user` is inserted, the `UserEntityListener#PostInsert` kicks in, and it forwards the `user` to the `Notifier` via a `.publish` call. The `Notifier` uses `<?>` for the data type, and it calls the interested parties via a `Callable`-like interface:

```
public interface Notifiable {
    public <T> void onEvent(T data);
}
```

So now the implementation of this is called in the proper handler, but it has the generic type and I have to cast it manually (the handler knows the type it should recieve). My question is, can I do this without explicit casts? Is there a good framework that makes all this low-level tinkering useless? I'd like a centralized solution to bridge the gap, otherwise all the boilerplate's going to kill me.

EDIT Added relevant source.

Notifier class:

```
class Subscriber {
    public String topic;
    public Notifiable notifiable;
    public Subscriber(String topic, Notifiable n) {
        this.topic = topic;
        this.notifiable = n;
    }
}

public class Notifier {
    private static Notifier instance = null;
    private List<Subscriber> subscribers = new ArrayList<Subscriber>();

    public Notifier() {};
    public void subscribe(String topic, Notifiable n) {
        if (!this.hasSubscriber(topic, n)) {
            this.subscribers.add(new Subscriber(topic, n));
        }
    }
    public <T> void publish(String topic, T data) {
        for (Subscriber s : this.subscribers) {
            if (s.topic.equals(topic)) {
                s.notifiable.onEvent(data);
            }
        }
    }
    public Boolean hasSubscriber (String topic, Notifiable n) {
        for (Subscriber s : this.subscribers) {
            if (s.topic.equals(topic) && s.notifiable == n) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static Notifier getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Notifier();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Entity Listener:

```
@PostPersist
public void PostInsert(User u) {
    Notifier.getInstance().publish("user/new", u);
}
```

Socketio Handler:

```
Notifier.getInstance().subscribe("user/new", (new Notifiable() {
    @Override
    public <T> void onEvent(T data) {
        User u = (User) data;
        logger.info("User name: " + u.getUsername());
    }
}));
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your problem ... do you want only to avoid the explicit casting at the `Notifiable` implementation, is that it? Also, can you post the code of the `Notifier` class?

Comment: Hey, I added the relevant source code. There are two things I don't like about the solution: The first thing is the explicit casting in the handler object, since it expects a kind of payload, I'd like to express that more naturally. The second is, I'm sure there are more elegant approaches to the more general logic I described, I'm just not aware of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid the explicit casting making the following changes:

One, Make your Notifiable interface generic:

```
public interface Notifiable<T> {
    public void onEvent(T data);
}
```

Two, make Subscriber class also generic:

```
public class Subscriber<T> {
    public String topic;
    public Notifiable<T> notifiable;
    public Subscriber(String topic, Notifiable<T> n) {
        ...
    }
 }
```

Three, adapt Notifier class

```
public class Notifier {
    private static Notifier instance = null;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private List<Subscriber> subscribers = new ArrayList<Subscriber>();

    public Notifier() {};

    public <T> void  subscribe(String topic, Notifiable<T> n) {
        if (!this.hasSubscriber(topic, n)) {
            this.subscribers.add(new Subscriber<T>(topic, n));
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> void publish(String topic, T data) {
        for (Subscriber<T> s : this.subscribers) {
            if (s.topic.equals(topic)) {
                s.notifiable.onEvent(data);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Boolean hasSubscriber (String topic, Notifiable<T> n) {
        for (Subscriber<T> s : this.subscribers) {
           /* XXX: Beware, is safe to compare two notifiable
            * instances by their memory addresses??
            */
           if (s.topic.equals(topic) && s.notifiable == n) {
                return true;
           }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static Notifier getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Notifier();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Four, Socketio Handler:

```
Notifier.getInstance().subscribe("user/new", (new Notifiable<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(User data) {
        logger.info("User name: " + u.getUsername());
    }
}));
```

Comment: Would you agree that In this case, using raw types is acceptable because the publisher and consumer have an implicit contract about the actual type so no cast problems can appear and the notifier doesn't consume the data itself?

Comment: Yes, the use of raw types is OK here because the notifier doesn't consume the data itself (as you say it) ...